# Make certain pages available to logged-in users only

Tags: 7

I need some help and here is the issue:

I am building a site using Drupal 7.

I need to make certain pages only visible to logged-in users (each having their own username/password), other users should be simply redirected or shown an error message. Is this functionality maybe included in Drupal 7 itself or is there a module that does this (something simpler than Organic Groups)?

Answer (score 7):

You need to use [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) module for fine grained node view permissions.

> This module allows you to manage permissions for content types by role
>   and author. It allows you to specifiy custom view, edit and delete
>   permissions for each content type. **Optionally you can enable per
>   content access settings, so you can customize the access for each
>   content node.**

Comment: That module hasn't been updated since 2013, and is described as "not yet considered stable". Care to recommend one that's currently maintained?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to do it programmatically within a module or node (w/ PHP Input Filter), you could use [user_is_logged_in()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_is_logged_in/7) for something like this:

```
<?php
if (!user_is_logged_in()) drupal_not_found();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the Content Access module solves the problem well, it's an extra module and it's not stable yet on D7.

An alternative using only commonly used modules is:

1. Create the nodes but set them as unpublished
2. Create a node view, e.g. "role-restricted content". Show the full node's content to replicate the standard node/% display.
3. Restrict the view to your desired roles (e.g. "Role | Authenticated user")
4. Set the view path to something like:

   ```
   restricted-content/%
   ```
5. Set a contextual filter by Nid.
6. Remove the default "content is published" filter.

Now you will have a view that works just like node/%, except it also handles unpublished content and restricts by role.

Comment: The view would show the list of nodes even if they are unpublished, but the users without the right permission cannot still access the nodes.

Answer (score -1):

There is pretty simple programatic solution, you can read user role (and also if it is anonymous or registered) like this:

```
$roles=$GLOBALS['user']->roles;
```

you will get an array with roles of current user in $roles.

You can redirect that user depending on role with some logic using

```
drupal_goto ('url-of-the/page');
```